# LibUsbDotNet, no libusb-1.0.dll

Tags: c#, windows, libusb-1.0, libusbdotnet

I'm attempting to port some C source (Linux) using libusb to C# (Windows).  I successfully installed LibUsbDotNet on Windows 7.  Then I proceeded to add `using MonoLibUsb`, since it looks like the easiest path for porting.  However, when running there's an exception saying that `libusb-1.0.dll` is missing.  And indeed, I can't seem to find it in `C:\Windows\System32`.  So, two questions

1. Where can I find it?  Searching online hasn't revealed any handy installer packages.
2. Why isn't it installed as part of LibUsbDotNet?  AFAICS the lack of it makes half of LibUsbDotNet unusable.

Comment: It is winusb.dll on Windows.  Use [the right project](http://winusbnet.codeplex.com/) to get a decent start.

Comment: Well, since it's C code using libusb that I'm porting to C# was hoping to not have to jump to a completely different API.  But I guess it would be too easy if things just worked on Windows.

Comment: No, WinUsbNet doesn't seem to be a good option.  First, I can't get the INF-creator to actually create an INF-file.  Second, after using `zadig` to connect the winusb driver to my device I realised that while the entire world, including the USB spec, is using VID:PID, it won't help me at all with WinUsbNet.  Somehow I need to know some GUID (that is exposed in the defunct INF-creator, but not in zadig) in order to find the device I'm interested in!

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled under the same issue one year after your post while compiling a C# program using the LibUsbDotNet library:

```
PS C:\src\FaultMonitor\FaultMonitor\bin\Debug> .\FaultMonitor.exe -u
An error occured while executing the proxy:
libusb-1.0.dll not found. If this is a 64bit operating system, ensure that the 6
4bit version of libusb-1.0.dll exists in the '\Windows\System32' directory.
at MonoLibUsb.MonoUsbSessionHandle..ctor()
```

For anyone in a similar predicament, download the [libusb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/) library and extract the contents (you will need [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)). Within the extracted contents, copy the `\MS32\dll\libusb-1.0.dll` into your `C:\windows\SysWOW64\` folder and copy the `\MS64\dll\libusb-1.0.dll` into your `C:\windows\System32\`. Afterwards, the program ran no problem:

```
PS C:\src\FaultMonitor\FaultMonitor\bin\Debug> .\FaultMonitor.exe -u
[15-10-23.02:09:05][+] Device: VendorID: 4203, ProductID: 63, Address: 1
[15-10-23.02:09:05][+] Device: VendorID: -32530, ProductID: 33, Address: 2
```

Comment: did not fix the problem on my end.. still have the same issue

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, restarting VS (2019), etc. Same error. This is a bit of a joke; installing LibUsbDotNet via NuGet just doesn't seem to been tested properly. And the doco mentions none of this.